# How to check changes made in specific files in project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs, getlatest

I am working on a solution on Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Premium, among a large group of developers. Every time someone makes changes in any file, i get the latest version of the solution and the `Output` Window gives a list with all the modified files. Problem is i want to check specific files in the project (.xml, .cs, etc). Is there a way to filter these files by their file extension or maybe by their folder location in the solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using GIT? If so, then yes, definitely. Try `git diff commitHashOlder commitHashYounger`

Comment: If it is TFS, right click on file > Source Control > Compare . Or if there are many files then you can do same on project history and compare. It would show a set of files modified and right click on each file and compare.

Comment: @eddyP23 No GIT, unfortunately..

Comment: @SivaGopal is there a way to filter files by their file extension? I would like to see only .cs set of files in the project history

Comment: I think that option is not available in TFS.

Comment: May be you can try [this plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexandrBiryukov.TFSSourceControlHistoryVisualization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is using [tf check out command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/checkout-or-edit-command).

There's an **itemspec** you could pass, and an itemspec could contain **wildcards**.

> *itemspec*
>
> Specifies the scope of the items to check in. For syntax, see [Use
>   Team Foundation version control commands](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands).

For example, you could use below command  to check out all `.cs` fils under a folder.

```
tf checkout /recursive *.cs
```